# Parallel voltage source concept

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, potential, electrical-resistance, batteries

I am having doubt understanding this:

If two voltage sources V1 and V2 are connected in parallel with different voltages like 2v and 3v is it possible or the scenario is wrong.

An example is this circuit

[image]

Tried solution:

[image]

Comment: Will create a short circuit if no resistor is included--in theory infinite current.

Comment: Exact duplicate of [What happens when non-equal voltages are put in parallel?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/65584/9887)

Comment: Thanks for your responses ,i have added abd example problem as well to make my question clearer . Here if you see the first connection its showing 4v in parallel with 12 a

Comment: There is only one voltage source in the image, i.e., there are no parallel connected voltage sources in the schematic you have provided as an example of parallel connected voltage sources.  I do, however, see a voltage source in parallel with a *current* source.

Comment: If you convert the current aource to voltage source it will be 24v in parallel with 4v or i am wrong ?

Comment: (1) if you discarded all of the circuit elements to the right of the 12A current source, you could do the Norton to Thevenin conversion you're thinking of but (2), the 2 ohm resistor changes from parallel to series, i.e., the two voltage sources would not be in parallel but would be separated by the 2 ohm series resistor.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri that clarified everything ,thanks a lot 

Comment: If you're attempting to reduce the 4V voltage source, 2 ohm resistor, and 12A current source to a Thevenin form in order to solve the rest of the circuit, think very carefully about it.  Hint:  the voltage across the parallel combination can *only* be 4V and the short circuit current is 'infinite'.

Comment: Yes i am having problem in finding the current because the 4Vx in parallenr with 16v means Vx will be 4v and that means in 4ohm register current will be 1amp but its not the correct one ,tring to figure out how i can simply solve it

Comment: Updated the image with my tried solution

Comment: As has been pointed out there is no problem with the left hand side of the circuit. This circuit requires little algebraic manipulation but it does require an understanding of what the circuit symbols mean.  To answer the question the only important part of the left hand side of the circuit is the $4\,\rm V$ voltage source which fixes the potential of the left hand side of the "horizontal" parallel circuit to $+4\,\rm V$ relative to the "bottom".The potential of the right hand side of the "horizontal" parallel circuit is given and so $V_{\rm x}$ can be found. d. Now use Kirchhoff's current law

Comment: @Farcher so the circuit can be represented as 4V (-+)series with registor 4ohm in series with voltage of 16 volt (+-) i.e 4-4i-16=0 in kvl , let me know if i am wrong

Comment: I'm afraid the Norton to Thevenin conversion you did in your work isn't correct.  As I wrote an earlier comment, that would only be appropriate if you discard all circuit elements to the right of the 12A current source.

Answer (score 1):

First, let me address what I think is an important conceptual error in your work.

If there were *only* the 4V voltage source, 2 ohm resistor and 12A current source (in other words, discard all the circuit elements to the right of the 12A current source), then you could make the Norton to Thevenin conversion that you did and then solve for the current through the 4V voltage source.

In other words, with just those three circuit elements, the voltage source 'can't tell the difference' between the 12A current source in parallel with a 2 ohm resistor and a 24V voltage source in series with a 2 ohm resistor.

However, since there *are* other circuit elements in addition to those three above, the conversion that you did is *conceptually* wrong.  The voltage source, as well as the circuit to the right of the 12A current source, '*can* tell the difference' between the original circuit and the one you've drawn.

---

*If* what you're trying to do is simplify the circuit in order to solve for $I_S$, then the first step is to completely remove the 2 ohm resistor and 4A current source.  Why?  *Because they are in parallel with a voltage source*.

Think *carefully* about this (I won't work this out here since that would probably be considered doing your homework for you).  When you do, you'll find that the *only* circuit variable the 2 ohm resistor and 12A current source can affect is the current through the 4V voltage source - removing them will not change the value of $I_S$.  So remove them and solve for $I_S$.

---

Put another way, the Thevenin equivalent circuit, looking leftwards towards the 12A current source, is just a 4V voltage source.

I would like for you to work out this Thevenin equivalent for yourself and then post your work as an answer to your own question.

Comment: It really helped but i have not learnt network theorems and its from my basic circuit problem section, With only using kcl or kvl if i want to solve how can i do that? I dont want to get a solution just want some guidance